# php regex: Alternative to backreference in negative lookbehind

Tags: php, regex, negative-lookbehind

I want to find instances where a captured group does not appear later in the string:

```
aaaBbb  = CccBbb  <- format is valid, skip
aaaDddd = CccDddd <- format is valid, skip
aaaEeee = CccFfff <- format is not valid, match this one only
```

So this matches the lines I don't want to match ( https://regex101.com/r/lon87L/1 )

```
/^ +\w+([A-Z][a-z+]) += +\w+\1$/mg
```

I've read on https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html that php doesn't support backreferences inside a negative lookbehind, but other implementations of regex can. So something like this would match the invalid lines that I want to match, but it doesn't work in php:

```
/^ +\w+([A-Z][a-z+]) += +\w+(?<!\1)$/mg
```

Is there anything else that would work, other than matching all of three lines and looping through the matches in a php foreach?

Comment: Negative lookbehinds require a compile time fixed length. A backreference is a runtime item with variable length. One option  is to `(?>\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\w)+` and match the backreference. This is probably quicker too.

Comment: You can see it here https://regex101.com/r/6gfSBi/1 Btw, only the Dot-Net engine supports variable width lookbehinds (including backreferences).

Comment: If it has to be at the EOS, just add   a `$` after the backref https://regex101.com/r/QuXJLY/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using using a negative lookahead instead of a negative lookbehind. It works equally well, plus it works in PHP.

```
^ +\w+([A-Z][a-z]+) += +(?!\w+\1).*$
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/HjSQGB/3)

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/eOT8g)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to, right before each repeated `\w` after the `=`, use negative lookahead for `\1$`:

```
^ +\w+([A-Z][a-z]+) += +(?:(?!\1$)\w)+$
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/lon87L/2

But that only excludes a match if the backreference occurs *right at the end* of the string. If you want to ensure that the previously matched phrase doesn't occur *anywhere* within the final `\w`s, just remove the `$` from inside the repeated group:

```
^ +\w+([A-Z][a-z]+) += +(?:(?!\1)\w)+$
                                ^
```

https://regex101.com/r/lon87L/3